# REGEX Formatting massive dump files for Excel

Tags: regex, excel, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzT67.png)
I'm having a problem with REGEX and using it for what I need to do. I have a couple million lines across several dumpfiles I need to put into serviceable spreadsheets.

This is as far as I have been able to get.

The problem is trying to get them all to separate for me since excel doesn't import these very well as they are.

I've run into a snag where if the items are not the next in the list they aren't getting matched at all.

Also the problem where the lines are not always listed in the same particular order from object to object

This is the REGEX that's gotten me the furthest, but I'm thoroughly stuck now.

```
(?<=^Object\s{3})(\w*).(?:^Type\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DeviceId\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Alias\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*(?:^InstanceId\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Description\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Location\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^NetworkId\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^SerialNum\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DefaultRouter\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^EthernetId\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^IPAddress\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^SubnetMask\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^PPPSubnetMask\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Port\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DefaultPort\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^BACnetDeviceId\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^BacnetMSTPNetNum\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Baud\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DefaultBaud\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Channel\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^VersionNum\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Properties\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^FullName\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Password\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^SecurityLevel\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^CreatedBy\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Owner\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^InfinetCtlr\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^InfinetId\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^RefreshRate\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Format\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Value\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DBQualifier\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DatabaseMode\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^LogIntervalSecs\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^LogType\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Units\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Param1\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Param3\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Param4\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Param5\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^Param6\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^DefaultMode\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.(?:^XdriverFile\s{2,3}(\S*).*?)*.*?(?=^EndObject)
```

---

Here's an example of data I'm trying to get through:

```
   Object    CHWDifPrs07
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWDifPrs07
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   23 PM
    TimeLocked   6/16/2014 12   10  54 PM
    InstanceId   7439/17
    Channel     15
    Description      CHW DP 7


    Export   True
    Format   #.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Psi
    EndObject

    Object   CHWRTmp05
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWRTmp05
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    TimeLocked   6/16/2014 12   11  17 PM
    InstanceId   7439/12
    Channel     14
    Description      CHWR Temp 5

    Export   True
    Format   ###.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Deg.F
    EndObject

    Object   CHWRTmp06
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWRTmp06
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   23 PM
    TimeLocked   5/11/2011 4    43  48 PM
    InstanceId   7439/13
    Channel     12
    Description      ChwR Temp 6

    Export   True
    Format   ###.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Deg.F
    EndObject

    Object   CHWRTmp07
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWRTmp07
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   23 PM
    TimeLocked   5/11/2011 9    29  45 AM
    InstanceId   7439/14
    Channel     17
    Description      CHWR Temp 7

    Export   True
    Format   ###.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Deg.F
    EndObject

    Object   CHWSTmp05
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWSTmp05
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    TimeLocked   8/15/2014 10   25  30 AM
    InstanceId   7439/9
    Channel     13
    Description      CHWS Temp 5

    Export   True
    Format   ###.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Deg.F
    EndObject

    Object   CHWSTmp06
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWSTmp06
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    TimeLocked   5/11/2011 9    29  59 AM
    InstanceId   7439/10
    Channel     11
    Description      ChWS Temp 6

    Export   True
    Format   ###.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Deg.F
    EndObject

    Object   CHWSTmp07
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    CHWSTmp07
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    TimeLocked   5/11/2011 9    30  6:00 AM
    InstanceId   7439/11
    Channel     16
    Description      CHWS Temp 7

    Export   True
    Format   ###.##
    Size    400
    Port

    Units    Deg.F
    EndObject

    Object   SpaceRHF13
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    SpaceRHF13
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    AlarmInfo    True
    TimeLocked   8/27/2014 12   34  1:00 PM
    InstanceId   7439/8
    Channel     18
    Description      Space Relative Humidity F.13



    Export   True
    Format   %#.#
    Size    96
    Port


    ExtLogEnable     True
    AlarmLinks
    Root\Mia_SpaceRH_Hi     1    Enabled
    Root\Mia_SpaceRH_Low    2    Enabled
    EndObject

    Object   SpaceRHF15
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    SpaceRHF15
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    AlarmInfo    True
    TimeLocked   8/27/2014 12   33  35 PM
    InstanceId   7439/7
    Channel     20
    Description      Space Relative Humidity F.15



    Export   True
    Format   %###.#
    Size    96
    Port


    ExtLogEnable     True
    AlarmLinks
    Root\Mia_SpaceRH_Hi     1    Enabled
    Root\Mia_SpaceRH_Low    2    Enabled
    EndObject

    Object   SpaceRHH15
    Type     InfinityInput
    DeviceId     Terremark.FL\S300_3SC\S300_M08
    Alias    SpaceRHH15
    CreateTime   5/10/2011 12   2   22 PM
    AlarmInfo    True
    TimeLocked   11/4/2015 11   50  5:00 AM
    InstanceId   7439/6
    Channel     22
    Description      Space Relative Humidity H.15
```

Comment: Do you have to transform the file completely in one expression? It may be easier to get the formatting correct through a series of regex manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.
regexr.com/40506

Just took a hot minute to understand how stuff was actually working to make it work.

For others who come across this: If you have more than 10 groups in notepad++, reference them with $10,$11,$12,etc... for when you want to use the find/replace.

*have a habit of making or breaking regex

(?:These throwaway groups can still have (capture groups)inside of them)? And you can also make the whole thing conditional.

Putting the * after something means you are going to get a match regardless, very useful if you want to make empty groups to keep formatting of columns like I did.